# Understanding a proof about permutations from P.A.Grillet's "Abstract Algebra"

Tags: proof-verification, permutations, proof-explanation

I need a hand in understanding the following proof of the following theorem(by P.A.Grillet in his textbook "Abstract Algebra").

> Proposition $4.1$. Every permutation of $\{1,...,n \}$ is a product of transpositions.

The proof the the mentioned boo k:

> By induction on $n$. Proposition $4.1$ is vacuous if $n=1$. Let $n > 1$ and $\sigma \in S_{n}$. If $\sigma(n) = n$, then, by the induction hypothesis, the restriction of $\sigma$ to $\{1,...,n-1 \}$ is a product of transpositions; therefore $\sigma$ is a product of transpositions. If $\sigma(n) = j \neq n$, then $(nj)\sigma(n) = n$, $(nj)\sigma$ is a product of transpositions $(nj)\sigma = \tau_{1} \tau_{2} ... \tau_{r}$, and so is $\sigma = (nj)\tau_{1} \tau_{2} ... \tau_{r}$.

I have a trouble understand the following implications:
$\sigma(n) = n$, the restriction of $\sigma$ to $\{1,...,n-1 \} $ is product of transpositions $\Rightarrow \ \ \sigma$ is a product of transpositions. How do we get there(both rigorously and intuitively).

Comment: Let $\sigma'$ be the restriction. Then we can write $\sigma' = \tau_1 \cdots \tau_k$ where the $\tau_i$ are the transpositions. Then $\sigma = \tau_1 \cdots \tau_k$. If $\tau $ transposes $i,j$, and $l$ is different from both $i,j$ then $\tau(l) = l$.

Comment: The proof is by the existence of bubblesort: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is because  any permutation in $S_{n-1}$ is *ipso facto* a permutation in $S_n$, with $n$ fixed. You can consider the embedding
\begin{align*}
S_{n-1}&\longrightarrow S_n\\
\sigma&\longmapsto \left(\sigma'\colon i\mapsto\begin{cases}\sigma(i)&\text{if}\enspace 1\le i\le n-1,\\ n &\text{if}\enspace i=n.\end{cases}\right)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

They split this proof up into two cases:

- First, if $\sigma(n)=n$, then $\sigma$ only permutation on $\{1, 2, 3, ..., n-1\}$. Therefore, by the induction hypothesis, $\sigma$ is a product of transpositions.
- Otherwise, $\sigma(n) \neq n$. In this case, let's say $\sigma(n)=j$. Thus, in order to transform this permutation into the first case, we multiply it by $(nj)$ in order to get:
  $$((nj) \cdot \sigma)(n)=(nj)(\sigma(n))=(nj)(j)=n$$
  Thus, $(nj)\sigma$ is a permutation from the first case, meaning it is a product of transpositions. Thus, $(nj)\sigma=\tau_1\tau_2\tau_3 ... \tau_r$, so $\sigma=(nj)(nj)\sigma=(nj)\tau_1\tau_2\tau_3 ... \tau_r$, meaning $\sigma$ is also a product of transpositions.

Now, we have proved both cases leads to the conclusion, so the whole statement must be true.